# c++ for unix command line operation

Tags: c++, shell, unix

I have a remote unix shell which I log on often to checkout files with but the system keep resetting my locals setting when I logon to it.
I was planning to write the code to execute a list of commands when I log on.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
 char javah[]="JAVA_HOME=/appl/usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_20";
 char anth[]="ANT_HOME=/appl/usr/ant/instances/1.8.2";
 char path[]="PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH";

    system("bash");
    system("cd");
    system("cd insurancePPC.11");
    system("0x0C");
    system("ls");

    putenv(javah);
    putenv(anth);
    putenv(path);
    std::cout << "JAVA_HOME=" << getenv("JAVA_HOME");
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "ANT_HOME=" << getenv("ANT_HOME");
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "PATH=" << getenv("PATH");
    std::cout << "\n";

    system("cd tools");
    std::cout << "command executed successfully...\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this wasn't working as expected?

Comment: How do you plan to run this program on login? From, say, `~/.profile`? Why not just put the commands in `~/.profile` directly?

Comment: What does not work? Program does not output the changed environment variables?

Comment: @chepner because profile is wiped daily

Comment: Then are you planning on running this C program manually every time you log in? You can just as easily write a shell script  to run manually. In fact, you'll *need* to do that, since your C program cannot affect your login shell's environment, only its own. The best this program can do is generate a shell script to source, but then you might as well just write that shell script in the first place.

Comment: @Sandro I have added export but it still wasn't able to work properly.

Comment: @chepner sorry but I am not familiar with shell script

Comment: You are generating one with your C program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd` is a built in command of the shell and only affects the current process (i.e. the current running shell.)

When you run `system("cd insurancePPC.11");` it starts a new shell, that new shell changes the directory to insurancePPC.11 and exits. Your own process is unaffected by that `cd` command.

You are much better off writing these commands in a text file and run it as a shell script via the [source](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do) command.

Create a file named myenv.sh with this content:

```
JAVA_HOME=/appl/usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_20
export JAVA_HOME
ANT_HOME=/appl/usr/ant/instances/1.8.2
export ANT_HOME
PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
cd
cd insurancePPC.11
ls

echo JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME
echo ANT_HOME=$ANT_HOME
echo PATH=$PATH
cd tools
```

And from your command line run `source myenv.sh` Or if your shell supports it, use the shorthand `. myenv.sh`

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to write a C program here. Just save the following as `mysettings.sh`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/appl/usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_20
export ANT_HOME=/appl/usr/ant/instances/1.8.2
PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
cd tools
```

When you log in, run

```
. mysettings.sh
```